# Compare a database value with an external value in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, select, compare

I have a database running on SQL Server. Also I have a table named PDV_FINAL containing "Nom_PDV, Pre_PDV, POS_ID, PHONE", I want to compare PDV_FINAL.PHONE with a value called Caller_ID which is given manually and display PDV_FINALL into a form.

Comment: Are you asking for the SQL query `SELECT Nom_PDV, Pre_PDV, POS_ID, PHONE FROM PDV_FINAL WHERE PHONE = @Caller_ID` ? or how to bind the data into the form also?

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using simple where condition as below

```
 Select Nom_PDV, Pre_PDV, POS_ID, PHONE from PDV_FINAL 
     where Phone = @yourcaller_id
```